# Without using 'INTERSECT' , How to retrieve only the rows that exist in both tables?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, union

I am a beginner reading the book `Sams Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes (Fifth Edition)` to learn SQL.

Here is an expmple SQL query from the book from **Chapter 14 - Combining Queries**.

My question regarding a note which says about other `UNION` type - `INTERSECT`

Firstly - see the Structure of Tables from this [Db Structure - Image](https://learning.oreilly.com/api/v2/epubs/urn:orm:book:9780135182925/files/graphics/app01fig01.jpg)

Here is the Query

```
SELECT cust_name, cust_contact, cust_email
FROM Customers
WHERE cust_state IN ('IL','IN','MI')
INTERSECT
SELECT cust_name, cust_contact, cust_email
FROM Customers
WHERE cust_name = 'Fun4All'
ORDER BY cust_name, cust_contact;
```

In the note after this example, it says that

> INTERSECT can be used to retrieve only the rows that exist in both tables.

**And Below that line**

> **In practice, however, these UNION types are rarely used because the same results can be accomplished using joins.**

**So, How can I accomplish this using joins and not `INTERSECT`.
I tried doing all I learned but couldn't get the result.**

Kindly help by sharing the required query.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what practice they are talking about. We use intersect & except frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INTERSECT` and `INNER JOIN` can get similar results, but there are a few caveats:

- `INTERSECT` (that is `INTERSECT DISTINCT`, which is the default operation) removes duplicates from the result set. `INNER JOIN` does not do this on its own. So if you have multiple instances of a customer in your Customers table, then `INTERSECT` and `INNER JOIN` will behave differently, unless you do `SELECT DISTINCT`.
- A join condition such as `INNER JOIN ... ON x = y` will not match on NULL values and therefore rows with NULL in one of the conditions would get excluded, whereas `INTERSECT` would match. To get the same effect with join conditions, use the `<=>` operator which matches NULL values.

In your example query there is only one table. Therefore, you can get the same result as that from your example query even without a `JOIN`. Just use a `SELECT DISTINCT` and combine the `WHERE` conditions with an `AND`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cust_name, cust_contact, cust_email
FROM Customers
WHERE cust_state IN ('IL','IN','MI') AND cust_name = 'Fun4All'
ORDER BY cust_name, cust_contact;
```

You could of course use a `JOIN` if you really wanted to, or in the case you did have two different tables. If so, it could look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.cust_name, c1.cust_contact, c1.cust_email
FROM Customers c1
  INNER JOIN Customers c2 ON 
    c1.cust_name <=> c2.cust_name AND 
    c1.cust_contact <=> c2.cust_contact AND 
    c1.cust_email <=> c2.cust_email
WHERE c1.cust_state IN ('IL','IN','MI') AND c2.cust_name = 'Fun4All'
ORDER BY c1.cust_name, c1.cust_contact;
```

The `INNER` keyword is optional.

If your data doesn't have duplicates or NULL values, or if you don't care about getting exactly the same results as with `INTERSECT`, then you drop `DISTINCT` and use the regular equality operator in the join conditions.

Comment: Thank You. It worked like a charm.

Comment: None of the two queries is equivalent to the INTERSECT one.

Comment: Thank you @ypercubeᵀᴹ for pointing that out. I have attempted to improve the answer after doing some research.

Comment: The 2nd would be correct if you joined on (cust_name, cust_contact, cust_email) and not on cust_id. I can't see a way to make the 1st method right.

Comment: Hi @ypercubeᵀᴹ Can you please tell.. what's wrong with the first query of dbdemon? I mean.. I get correct results.

Comment: Also.. why `cust_id` should not be used in 2nd one? It as well works and I believe `DISTINCT` is not even required @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Comment: I've modified the answer again. I think in the 2nd query, the idea is to show how you would do the query if you did have two tables with different data, so in that case you have to join on the SELECTed columns.

Comment: The problem with the 2nd query, i.e. with joining on (cust_id) vs joining on (cust_name, cust_contact, cust_email) is that you may have rows with different cust_id but same cust_name, cust_contact and cust_email (and potentially vice versa (if cust_id is not unique). If that is the case, you'll get different results. It doesn't matter if you get same results in your data, just add another row with same (cust_name, cust_contact and cust_email ) as an existing row and you'll see. So the join needs to be done on the same columns as the INTERSECT, which is these 3 columns.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - that is what the answer says now - and more! (Too long, though?) I'm not sure what you have against my first query, and RJ has given a similar answer. Are you forgetting that the question is really about just one table, not two different tables? I can insert another row with the same (cust_name, cust_contact and cust_email) as an existing row, and I still get the same result as I do with INSERSECT.

Comment: Thank You. I cleared much of my doubts and learnt new things.

Comment: Aggh, I hadn't noticed initially that cust_name is used in both the (2nd) WHERE condition and the INTERSECT/JOIN column list. That is why your first query works - in the specific example.

Comment: So I retract my first statement. The first query is ok for the specific example where  one of the conditions is a column that is also in the SELECT list (that is being intersected). It's not ok in general (but give some time to construct an example)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is what you want:

```
SELECT  cust_name, cust_contact, cust_email
    FROM  Customers
    WHERE  cust_state IN ('IL','IN','MI')
      AND  cust_name = 'Fun4All'
    ORDER BY  cust_name, cust_contact;
```

This would help performance:

```
INDEX(cust_name)
```